# got error undefined is not in object(Evaluting this.props=props)

Tags: react-native

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  responsieHeight,
  responsiveHeight,
} from 'react-native-responsive-dimensions';


class App extends Component(){
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
this.state={Hi:false}
}


  render(){
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <SafeAreaView>

              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.setState({Hi: true})}
                style={{
                  marginHorizontal: 30,
                  height: responsiveHeight(8),
                  backgroundColor: '#000',
                  borderRadius: 40,
                  marginVertical: 5,
                }}></TouchableOpacity>


      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
            }
};



export default App;
```

i don't know why this error occur,as it due to props on constructor or changing state in touchableOpacity or this is some error related to mobile Phone,i just change View to TouchableOpacity and then start such error,,and now this error happen again and again

Answer (score 2):

change :

```
class App extends Component(){
```

to:

`/// it's a Class not a function
class App extends Component {`

check the expo slack:
https://snack.expo.io/@saadqbal/96c70b